# Use Quadrilateration to locate a point

Tags: geometry, spheres, intersection-theory

I'm having lots of trouble with this. At first I thought the problem was a matter of equating four spheres to find their one common point, i.e. point of intersection. I've looked up lots of things on trilateration, which makes perfect sense to me, however I'm just missing something when it comes to quadrilateration, which is necessary for this problem because not all points will lie on the z=0 plane.

The ultimate aim is to make a program which will use quadrilateration to find the (x,y,z) coordinates of a point, given an input of the radii, and the amount each sphere has been shifted away along any of the axes ($a_n, b_n, c_n$). Therefore an ideal answer would be a derivation of a general formula for finding said point.

Here's what I have done so far:

- I began by defining n spheres as follows:

$$
(x-a_n)^2 +(y-b_n)^2+(z-c_n)^2=r_n^2
$$

(As I only need 4 spheres, n will range from 1-4)

- Next, I isolated $x^2$:

$$
x^2=r_n^2-(y-b_n)^2-(z-c_n)^2+2a_nx-a_n^2
$$

I did the same for y and z. This is where I get confused: I have 4 equations (for the 4 spheres) but only 3 unknowns (the coordinate of their overlap). Am I doing something wrong, or is there something I'm missing? This is a steady-state problem and shouldn't be too complex but I just can't find anything online to help me, everything seems to be related to GPS, however that takes into account the relative motion of the satellites which complicates things.

Any and all help will be really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: The system is of sixth degree, so it is quite complex. Anyway I suggest to expand the squares, find four equations of the kind $x^2+y^2+z^2+p_nx+q_ny+r_nz=s_n$. From these four equations find three equations subtracting one of them from the others. These will give you a linear system that (maybe) have one solution, if it has not try with another combination of the four equations.

Comment: Adding a fourth sphere seems unnecessary to me. Since three points are always coplanar, you can find a coordinate system in which three sphere centers have a zero as their last coordinate. After transforming to this coordinate system, you can use standard trilateration formulas.

Comment: @amd With three spheres you will get two possible points: the fourth sphere is necessary to decide which point is the right one.

Comment: @Aretino Fair point. I had in mind the typical application of trilateration in which you’ve got some other way to choose between the two solutions, such as solid ground to one side of the reference plane.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I ended up going with what @Aretino suggested and obtained 3 linear equations for the 3 planes. This was enough to put into the program and find a point.

Comment: Keep in mind that quadrilateration is important in applications like GPS, not to distibnguish between two points (for which you can use other means, as @amd says), but to solve for a 4th state variable, which is the unknown time scale bias.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection between two spheres is a circle, lying in a plane whose equation you can find by subtracting the equation of one sphere from that of the other one (the equations must be normalized so that $x^2$, $y^2$ and $z^2$ all have unit coefficient). This plane is perpendicular to the line joining the centers of the spheres.

If three spheres intersect at a point, the three circles you get from their pairwise intersections have two points in common. That happens because the planes of those circles are all perpendicular to the plane defined by the centers of the spheres, so they must have a line in common.

A fourth sphere is then needed to choose the right point. Given the equations of the spheres, a practical way to find their intersection point (assuming it exists) could be as follows:

- subtract the equation of the first sphere from the equation of the second one, to get the equation of plane $\alpha$;
- subtract the equation of the second sphere from the equation of the third one, to get the equation of plane $\beta$;
- subtract the equation of the third sphere from the equation of the fourth one, to get the equation of plane $\gamma$;
- those three planes should have a single point in common, which is the one you are seeking. To find its coordinates, just solve the linear system formed with the equations of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: There is something that bugs me here When you intersect three planes there is a solution unless that third plane is parallel to the line of intersection between the other two planes. 

It seems to me that the situation of having a fourth sphere that intersects exactly one of the two possible points is a more constrained condition. Am I wrong?

Comment: The above algorithm works IF the four given spheres have a point in common. Otherwise the solution you may get makes no sense.